# Unreal engine build fails on google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, unreal-engine4

I follow the steps specified in [docs](https://microsoft.github.io/AirSim/build_linux/):

```
git clone -b 4.25 git@github.com:EpicGames/UnrealEngine.git
```

which results in:

```
Cloning into 'UnrealEngine'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I found a workaround by connecting my github account with EpicGames following the instructions [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Linux/BeginnerLinuxDeveloper/SettingUpAnUnrealWorkflow/). Then I fork the UnrealEngine [repo](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine) which is a private repo and you can't access it unless you connect your github account as specified earlier. Then I clone the fork:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://username:token@github.com/username/UnrealEngine.git
```

which results in

```
Cloning into 'UnrealEngine'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 111586, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (111586/111586), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (83748/83748), done.
remote: Total 111586 (delta 26650), reused 92556 (delta 24736), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (111586/111586), 236.57 MiB | 17.26 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (26650/26650), done.
Checking out files: 100% (137999/137999), done.
```

Followed by the instructions specified in [docs](https://microsoft.github.io/AirSim/build_linux/)

```
cd UnrealEngine
./Setup.sh
./GenerateProjectFiles.sh
make
```

Which work perfectly fine until I get an error at the later stages of the build as shown below. You can check the full build log [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11JjCTpVRjgXbHGIFcteQLgSo5QFKI1sE/view?usp=sharing)

```
                     ... truncated for readability
./v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/librpcsvc.a
./v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libpthread.a
./v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libmcheck.a
./v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libnss_nisplus.so
./v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/crt1.o
./v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libnss_dns.so
./v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/Scrt1.o
./v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libc.a
./v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libBrokenLocale.so
./v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/usr/lib64/libnsl.a

Target arch set to: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Building ThirdParty libraries

If you don't see SUCCESS message in the end, then building did not finish properly.
In that case, take a look into /content/UnrealEngine/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/BuildThirdParty.log for details.

No third party libs needed to be built locally

**********  SUCCESS ****************
Setup successful.
Attempting to set up UE4 pretty printers for gdb (existing UE4Printers.py, if any, will be overwritten)...
    updated UE4Printers.py
    no ~/.gdbinit file found - creating a new one.

Setting up Unreal Engine 4 project files...

Fixing inconsistent case in filenames.
Setting up Mono
Generating data for project indexing... 100%
Generating data for project indexing... 100%
Writing project files... 100%
Generating data for project indexing... 100%
Generating data for project indexing... 100%
Generating data for project indexing... 100%
Generating data for project indexing... 100%
Writing project files... 100%
bash "/content/UnrealEngine/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/Build.sh" CrashReportClient Linux Shipping  
Fixing inconsistent case in filenames.
Setting up Mono
Running command : Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe CrashReportClient Linux Shipping
Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build (/content/UnrealEngine).
Creating makefile for CrashReportClient (no existing makefile)
Creating makefile for UnrealHeaderTool (no existing makefile)
------- Build details --------
Using toolchain located at '/content/UnrealEngine/Engine/Extras/ThirdPartyNotUE/SDKs/HostLinux/Linux_x64/v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'.
Using clang (/content/UnrealEngine/Engine/Extras/ThirdPartyNotUE/SDKs/HostLinux/Linux_x64/v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/clang++) version '10.0.1' (string), 10 (major), 0 (minor), 1 (patch)
Using bundled libc++ standard C++ library.
Using lld linker
Using llvm-ar : /content/UnrealEngine/Engine/Extras/ThirdPartyNotUE/SDKs/HostLinux/Linux_x64/v17_clang-10.0.1-centos7/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/llvm-ar
Using fast way to relink  circularly dependent libraries (no FixDeps).
------------------------------
Performing 38 actions (2 in parallel)
[1/38] Compile PCH.Core.h
[2/38] Compile PCH.CoreUObject.h
[3/38] Compile BuildSettings.cpp
[4/38] Compile Module.TraceLog.cpp
[5/38] Compile SharedPCH.Core.ShadowErrors.h
[6/38] Compile Module.Core.4_of_14.cpp
[7/38] Compile Module.Core.12_of_14.cpp
[8/38] Compile Module.Core.11_of_14.cpp
[9/38] Compile Module.Core.7_of_14.cpp
[10/38] Compile Module.Core.10_of_14.cpp
[11/38] Compile Module.Core.9_of_14.cpp
[12/38] Compile Module.Core.2_of_14.cpp
[13/38] Compile Module.Core.6_of_14.cpp
[14/38] Compile Module.Core.5_of_14.cpp
[15/38] Compile Module.Core.13_of_14.cpp
[16/38] Compile Module.Core.8_of_14.cpp
[17/38] Compile Module.Core.3_of_14.cpp
[18/38] Compile Module.Core.1_of_14.cpp
[19/38] Compile Module.Core.14_of_14.cpp
[20/38] Link (lld) libUnrealHeaderTool-TraceLog.so
[21/38] Link (lld) libUnrealHeaderTool-BuildSettings.so
[22/38] Compile Module.Json.cpp
[23/38] Link (lld) libUnrealHeaderTool-Core.so
[24/38] Compile Module.Projects.cpp
[25/38] Link (lld) libUnrealHeaderTool-Json.so
[26/38] Compile Module.CoreUObject.6_of_8.cpp
[27/38] Link (lld) libUnrealHeaderTool-Projects.so
[28/38] Compile Module.CoreUObject.2_of_8.cpp
[29/38] Compile Module.CoreUObject.7_of_8.cpp
[30/38] Compile Module.CoreUObject.1_of_8.cpp
[31/38] Compile Module.CoreUObject.8_of_8.cpp
[32/38] Compile Module.CoreUObject.4_of_8.cpp
[33/38] Compile Module.CoreUObject.5_of_8.cpp
[34/38] Compile Module.CoreUObject.3_of_8.cpp
[35/38] Compile Module.UnrealHeaderTool.cpp
[36/38] Link (lld) libUnrealHeaderTool-CoreUObject.so
[37/38] Link (lld) UnrealHeaderTool
[38/38] UnrealBuildTool.exe UnrealHeaderTool.target
Total time in Local executor: 472.22 seconds
Parsing headers for CrashReportClient
  Running UnrealHeaderTool CrashReportClient "/content/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/CrashReportClient/Shipping/CrashReportClient.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -abslog="/content/UnrealEngine/Engine/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Log_UHT.txt"
src/tcmalloc.cc:283] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x7fab74511030 
Makefile:327: recipe for target 'CrashReportClient-Linux-Shipping' failed
make: *** [CrashReportClient-Linux-Shipping] Error 3
```

I tried solutions to similar issues proposed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/AirSim/issues/686), [here](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/unreal-fails-to-build-on-linux/77732), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/hs9mv6/build_failed_in_linux_ubuntu_1804_recipe_for/) and nothing seems to fix the problem, and some cause other errors.

Comment: Cool have you found any workaround? or any alternative cloud resources?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it performs a wrongful memory deallocation (likely deallocating twice):

```
Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x7fab74511030
```

This might be a better place to ask: https://issues.unrealengine.com

Comment: This looks like a read-only thing, I can't ask new questions through this link. Maybe you meant [this](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/ask.html) one